# How can I view the contents of a pointer file in Git LFS?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a Git LFS repo and locally I've already pulled all the LFS files. I would like to inspect the 'pointer' files LFS uses, but all I can see are the actual LFS binary files.

Where/how can I explicitly see the pointer files in git, rather than the binary files they point to?

Comment: `git show HEAD:<path>` will almost certainly do the trick, as will `git cat-file -p :<path>`. I'm not sure what good that does you though.

Comment: @torek I want to see what's inside. Isn't it a human-readable text file?

Comment: It is: it's a four-line file with a hash ID as the key to obtaining the content. See https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/spec.md

Comment: @torek - the show/cat-file commands are the answer to this question.  Could you post them as an "answer"?  They're useful if one explicitly wants to see the LFS pointer file, not the blob stored in LFS.

Comment: @PFee: These commands will *sometimes* obey text conversion filters. The details depend on your particular Git version and command line options and arguments. I'd have to dig into the release notes to find more details, but a quick way to hack around `git show` doing conversions is probably to use `-c` to fake out the smudge filter. (I don't actually *use* Git-LFS so I can't experiment to find out, alas.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to "git lfs pull" in your local, then you can see the lfs file content.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

You can see the content of the pointer file with:

```
$ git cat-file -p :path/to/myfile.a
```

### More details

The [specs](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/spec.md) are pretty clear and quite small. I don't know all the details, but my understanding is the following:

When using git-lfs, it creates (among others) a folder `.git/lfs` where the heavy files will be downloaded (can be seen in the output of `$ git lfs env`). Those files are not saved with the git history, but separately (e.g. in https://git-lfs.github.com). What git versions is pointers to those files, which look like the following:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:907b5c652cce59e009e3c7fb2dc92d3bf598251315bed741aee037f2046bd32e
size 251222
```

This is the content of a pointer in my repo, for a file (say `path/to/myfile.a`), and which I showed with the following command:

```
$ git cat-file -p :path/to/myfile.a
```

*Note that `path/to/myfile.a` is relative to the root of the repository.*

From the `oid` above, we can find the file that was downloaded by git-lfs into `.git/lfs`, in my case it's here:

```
.git/lfs/objects/90/7b/907b5c652cce59e009e3c7fb2dc92d3bf598251315bed741aee037f2046bd32e
```

Now if you just `git clone` your repo and have git-lfs installed, you will have the full file at `path/to/myfile.a`. But it's interesting to actually clone the repo without LFS:

```
$ GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git clone <repository>
```

And you will see that now `myfile.a` is the pointer file!